# How do I stop infinite scroll ajax post from getting double the results sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that works OK and it appends results to existing results. The problem is that sometimes the function seems to fire twice and it returns double the amount of data I am expecting.

It doesn't happen every time but 1 in 5 times maybe. I think its the nature of the scroll hitting the bottom. I tried adding 'var ajaxRunning' as below but it still happens. Does anyone know a solution?

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {    
var lastID = jQuery('.load-more').attr('lastID');        
var ajaxRunning = false;

    if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight ) {       
        ajaxRunning = true;                
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'getData.php',
                data:'id='+pager + '&location='+loc,                
                beforeSend:function(){
                    jQuery('.load-more').show();
                },
                success:function(html){
                    jQuery('.load-more').remove();
                    jQuery('#results').append(html);
                    pager++;
                },
            complete: function() {
            ajaxRunning = false;
            }
     });
}};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `ajaxRunning` globally and use it in the `if` condition:

```js
var ajaxRunning = false;

window.onscroll = function(ev) {
  var lastID = jQuery('.load-more').attr('lastID');
  if (!ajaxRunning && (window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset >= document.body.offsetHeight)) {
    ajaxRunning = true;
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'getData.php',
      data: 'id=' + pager + '&location=' + loc,
      beforeSend: function() {
        jQuery('.load-more').show();
      },
      success: function(html) {
        jQuery('.load-more').remove();
        jQuery('#results').append(html);
        pager++;
      },
      complete: function() {
        ajaxRunning = false;
      }
    });
  }
};
```